# Iterate over unique values in a column(a) and create plots (x,y) for each unqiue value in column a

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe (DF) with Stock as one of the column names having unique values such as `['AAPL', 'MSFT']`. Other columns in DF are Date and Price.

[image]

I am trying to create a line plot based on filter condition applied to the DataFrame so that I can get two separate lines on a plot individually for Stock = 'AAPL' and 'MSFT' for Date Vs. Price.

In other words, I am trying to use a condition on column Stock to filter/subset the dataframe DF and then automate / iterate over Stock unique values to plot (Date vs. Price) on the same plot.

There is a longer method to create two temporary Dataframes by applying the condition on Stock and then plot them, but I am trying to avoid this solution and automate the code to iterate over unqiue values in Stock column and create a plot for all individual values.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn makes it easy by allowing you to pass your categorical column Stock as a `hue` parameter, which makes a different colored line for each stock in the df.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date',y='Price', hue='Stock')
```